# Android button default colour: sometimes grey, sometimes clear?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is an odd one, but I've been making an app in Android Studio, and I've got one activity with buttons which look different to the buttons in the other activities. The buttons in this one activity are grey, whereas they're transparent on the other activities. I haven't made any changes to them other than the text, apart from that they're default buttons. When I copy a button from one of the other activities, the copied button goes grey too. I figure it must be some sort of style coming from the activity settings, but I can't figure out what it is.

XML from activity with transparent buttons:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}"
android:background="@color/custom_yellow"
android:clickable="false"
android:id="@+id/rlLoginLayout">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/bttnLogInText"
    android:id="@+id/bttnLogIn"
    android:onClick="logIn"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/chckbxKeepLoggedIn"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edttxtPassword"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/edttxtPassword" />
```

XML from activity with grey buttons:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}"
android:background="@color/custom_yellow"
android:clickable="false"
android:id="@+id/rlOptions" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Option 1"
    android:id="@+id/bttnOption1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="listOption1" />
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testapp" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OptionsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_options" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: post both xml's please

Comment: Also post the manifest where the activities are declared.

Comment: Added those bits of code.